# The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state

Tags: wcf-client

I am getting following:

```
System.ServiceModel.Comm
unicationObjectFaultedException: The communication object, 
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
Server stack trace: at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)

Exception rethrown at [0]: at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.Close()
at MicrosoftIT.BGCOE.EndItem.ServiceFacade.BizServiceClient.GetUserID(String userAlias)
at MicrosoftIT.BGCOE.EndItem.Import.ImportBatchSet.Init()
at MicrosoftIT.BGCOE.EndItem.BatchProcessing.BatchProcessor.ProcessBatchSet(IBatchSet set)
at MicrosoftIT.BGCOE.EndItem.Service.ImportService.importServiceTimer_Elapsed(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this issue. I made my client to run with actual service account instead of local machine account. This resolved the issue.